# Erro ao tentar efetuar um Relacionamento belongsToMany no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, viewmodel

Estou tentando efetuar um relacionamento belongsToMany em minha Model mas está trazendo o erro:

> QueryException
>       SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'api.codigo' doesn't exist (SQL: select `sequenciaaprovacaos`.*, `codigo`.`sequencia` as `pivot_sequencia`, `codigo`.`sequenciaaprovacao_id` as `pivot_sequenciaaprovacao_id` from `sequenciaaprovacaos` inner join `codigo` on `sequenciaaprovacaos`.`id` = `codigo`.`sequenciaaprovacao_id` where `codigo`.`sequencia` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51))

**Minhas Models**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class SequenciaUsuario extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'sequencia_usuarios';

    protected $fillable = [

        'sequencia',
        'recnum',
        'usuario',
        'qtde_aprova',
        'ordem'
    ]; 


    public function grupos()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\CadSequenciaAprovacao', 'codigo','sequencia');
    }

    public function cadastro()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\CadUsuario','cod_adm');
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class CadSequenciaaprovacao extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sequenciaaprovacaos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'codigo',
        'descricao',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CadSequenciaUsuario','sequencia');
    }

}
```

Comment: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Model\CadSequenciaAprovacao', 'codigo','sequencia');` aqui te está errado, qual é o nome da tabela intermediária! tem como colocar o diagrama de banco?

Comment: Troquei de belongsToMany para hasMany parou de dar o erro!

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas opções que você pode testar. Como você não está usando o nome padrão da tabela (vide necessidade de informar o atributo $table), é interessante que você informe o relacionamento passando todos os parametros aceitos pelo Eloquent para esse método.

`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');`

no qual

- `App\Role` coincide com seu model;
- `role_user` coincide com a sua tabela; `user_id` coincide com a sua
- fk na tabela e PK na sua tabela que relaciona;
- `role_id` coincide com a sua fk na tabela que é PK na tabela com a qual você quer relacionar;

Para mais informações, veja [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) a documentação neste ponto.

Espero ter ajudado.